# Making opera forget about a position in hyperlink

Tags: opera, opera-10

How to make opera forget about a «position» part of the hyperlink just after it is followed? (This is useful when I want to reload page and keep position where I am reading, while the original link has its own position specified.)

Opera-10.52_pre6272, Gentoo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This UserJS solves the issue:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name PurgeAnchor
// @include *
// ==/UserScript==
(function() {
 var reg=/^(.*)\#(.*)$/;
 var match=reg.exec(location);
 function ObjectPosition(obj) {
    var curtop = 0;
    if(obj.offsetParent)
        while(1)
        {
          curtop += obj.offsetTop;
          if(!obj.offsetParent)
            break;
          obj = obj.offsetParent;
        }
    else if(obj.y)
        curtop += obj.y;
    return curtop;
 }
 if(match) {
    location.href=match[1];
    sessionStorage.setItem("anchor", match[2]);
 }
 window.addEventListener("load", (function() {
         var anchor=sessionStorage.getItem("anchor");
         if(anchor!==null) {
             var obj=document.getElementById(anchor);
             if(obj===null) {
                 obj=document.getElementsByName(anchor)[0];
             }
             var pos=0;
             if(obj!==null) {
                 pos=ObjectPosition(obj);
                 window.scrollTo(0, pos);
             }
             sessionStorage.removeItem("anchor");
         }
     }), false);
 })()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you have followed a link with a [fragment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) specified (the part after the hash sign), why not just press <kbd>F5</kbd> to reload the page? Are you going to the address bar and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> or something?

Comment: If I used F5 I got positioned according to the fragment identifier. Now I don't. Was this was fixed in new opera?

Comment: @ZyX: I don't know. I don't think I ever saw the behavior you describe.

Comment: Strange: on one site (unixforum.org, Russian forum about linux) I do not get positioned after reload. On other site (habrahabr.ru, Russian IT blog) I do get positioned after reload. So I still want to know how to make Opera forget about a fragment identifier.

Comment: Update: on unixforum I also get positioned on reload, but not if I use link with post number. I used it now only because it was the fastest way to check your answer, so I never noticed such strange behavior.

Comment: Another update: forget about strange behavior, the problem was that I do not get positioned only if I scroll not enough to make the target element invisible.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried again and Opera did as you said - when I reloaded, it went to the fragment ID in the URL. I don't know why I didn't notice it before - perhaps because it's a recent change and I don't often refresh a page I'm in the middle of reading. I would consider it to be a bug - perhaps you would like to [report it](http://www.opera.com/support/bugs/) to Opera Software? I can confirm the same behavior on the Windows version (10.51).

Anyway, here's a workaround: when I'm about to change zoom, which sometimes makes me lose my place, I select some text (preferably a few words from within a single paragraph) and copy it to the clipboard. Then after changing zoom (or in your case reloading), I search for the text I just copied (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>).